# Having issue with a Module (noob coder)

Tags: vb.net

I'm not so experienced and this is a noob question. Anyway I hope you'll be clement.
I created a little module in my vb.net application to not rewrite every time the same code.
So i created the module.vb

I put inside it, this code:

```
Module Save
Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
Dim PictureBox1 As New PictureBox
Public idname As String

Public Sub Save()
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = idname
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.png)|*.png|(*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.bmp)|*.bmp"
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    'End If #error while pasting :)
End Sub
End Module
```

In the form I call the module in this way:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     ToolStripSave.Click
    Save() 'before it was Save.Save(), but only Save() give me the error "Save is a type and cannot be used as expression."
End Sub
```

I run the debug and I get no errors but when I attempt to save the picture I get an error like this: 
'Save' is a type and cannot be used as expression.

Where I did mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not create a class/module called Save, and then create a sub that called Save as well, especially when you use a method called `Save`. Error or not, it's bad.

Second thing, I'm not sure what is that `End If` there, because there is no If statement. Either you forgot to write `If something Then` or you wrote `End If` by mistake.

Take a look [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=xcHYU6jtA_Sp0AX-n4C4BA&usg=AFQjCNFN2XHi7TG2-0irPZX9VBFwrsFF0A&bvm=bv.71778758,d.d2k&cad=rja) for more information about `SaveFileDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake in function call as this  `Save.Save()` we can directly call the `save()` method since it is declared as `public` within the module, so it having the **global scope**

Please do the following correction to the code and execute again:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     ToolStripSave.Click
    Save()
End Sub
```

Note: **Try to avoid keywords as function names**

Comment: If I use only Save() I get an error mark on it that tell: 'Save' is a type and cannot be used as expression.